# "The application must supply JDBC connections" while doing simplehibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, pom.xml, sessionfactory

I am running simple hibernate program ,but it is giving me error  mention in the title
My hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">rishabh123#</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.tut.ProjectwithMaven.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
    
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

My code is as follows:-

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
       // Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
       
            try {
                new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  try
                  {
                      throw (Throwable)e;
                  }
                  catch(Throwable ex)
                  {
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
                System.out.println("AAge");
            
        
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
        Student st=new Student();
        st.setId(101);
        st.setName("Rishabh");
        st.setCity("Bangalore");
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(st);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

Please help in resolving this issue, i have checked pom.xml ,it seems to be right,but still giving same error again and again

Comment: You are confusing pom.xml with hibernate.cfg.xml. The first is used by maven to declare dependencies and other stuff related to the lifecycle of the application. The second one is the hibernate configuration

Comment: Just for clarification: "_My pom.xml is as follows_" - What you are showing us in the question does not look like the contents of a **Maven** `pom.xml` file. It belongs in a **Hibernate** configuration file, which needs to be accessible to your application.

Comment: Yeah i have edited it ,it was typo ,so I meant to say that it was my hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: But it is giving me error

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not using this configuration file. See the line you posted:

```
SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
```

It should be

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```